# How to use htaccess code for URL rewrite in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a link like below:

In `/country/search.php`

```
<a href="<?php echo 'index.php?departments='.$value['department_id'].'&towns='.$value['town_id'].'&type='.$value['type_id'].'&id='.$value['id'] ?>">
```

When I use the below `.htaccess` code, it does nothing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /country/index.php?departments=$1&towns=$2&type=$3&id=$4 [L]
```

It does in the tool:

```
http://example.com/0/0/4/122
```

... but when I click that link it shows old URL again.

What is the problem here?

I'm generating that `.htaccess` code using this tool: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Comment: Your link already looks like the request you want to make - so what do you want to do?

Comment: yes.it does @kingkero.I want to make it like http://example.com/0/0/4/122 but htaccess code not working

Comment: htaccess code only rewrites your urls so that requests end up at the right place. the links you generate with your application are not affected by htaccess. You have to format it the right way yourself.

Comment: @rbtux can you guide me how to do it with me php showing some example please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(index\.php|)\?departments=([^\s&]*)&towns=([^\s&]*)&type=([^\s&]*)&id=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual URL
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /country/index.php?departments=$1&towns=$2&type=$3&id=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood what the rewrite rules are trying to achieve in this context.

F.e. this rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /app.php?method=$1&arg=$2
```

Will ensure that a request to http://example.com/mymethod/myarg will be rewritten to

```
http://example.com/app.php?method=mymethod&arg=myarg
```

When you generate links from within your application you should know how you contstructed the rewrite rules and you have to build the link accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Original URL:

```
href="news.php?state="<?php echo $sql_res['state']?>"&country="<?php echo $sql_res['country']?>
```

Ideal URL:

```
/India/andhra%20Pradesh
```

And .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /news.php?country=$1&state=$2 [L]
```

Comment: php code        <?php echo $sql_res['country']?>/<?php echo $sql_res['state']?>        .htaccess code         RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /news.php?country=$1&state=$2 [L]